# Cycles render showing up black and weird

Tags: rendering

I'm trying to make an awesome render of an office building in Blender 2.7. Here's what it looks like in my 3D workspace view so far.
[image: Before the render]

I've been toiling over the wire frame and 3D aspects of it, and then checking to see how it actually renders periodically. When I first started, it seemed to be rendering just fine. But then, when I was about 25% of the way done with building my model, I clicked render and this weird black image of it shows up. 
[image: After it renders]
Also, I'm quite certain that it doesn't have to do with the lighting, as I have 4 lamps placed around the scene. I'm starting to get a little concerned that when I'm all done with pouring hours into this, I'm not going to be able to render it properly. Does anyone know what might be going wrong?

edit: I tried adding a white material to the floor part with the chairs on it, but it showed up like this:

[image: after a plain white material was added to the floor]

Here is the .blend:
[image]

Comment: Have you recalculated the normals yet? Also, what sorts of materials do you have applied?

Comment: what material do you have on the building?

Comment: There are no materials yet, and I don't know how to recalculate normals or what that does. I'm a beginner, so could you tell me please?

Comment: About normals - http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?114883-The-Recalculate-Normals-command. Could you upload your blend file using http://www.pasteall.org/ or http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ because some parts of the model on render seem to be overlapping each other and it's hard to say what's going on.

Comment: sure thing. [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=263" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/263/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your entire building has a material on it "realistic glass"

[image]

Take this off and *viola* problem solved. If you would like to put glass on one part of the mesh see [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh) question.

[image]

Comment: Wow, you just solved all of my problems! Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem... if it's solved, click the little check mark next to the answer so we can close this case. thanks-